# Recursive aggregation of data tree

Tags: r, tree, aggregate, nodes, data.tree

I'm using the `data.tree` package to perform analysis instead of nested lists as my actual data ends up with the lists being too nested and quite difficult to work with.

I've put together sample data based off this question. [Aggregating values on a data tree with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225671/aggregating-values-on-a-data-tree-with-r).
In my own data I have the `to, from, hours` data and need to create the `actual_hours` data which is the sum of the children subtracted from the `hours` value for its parent node.

```
library(data.tree)
#Have
to <- c("Team1", "Team1-1","Team1-1", "Team1-1-1", "Team1-1-1", "Team1-1-1", "Team1-1-2")
from <- c("Team1-1", "Team1-1-1","Team1-1-2", "Team1-1-1a", "Team1-1-1b", "Team1-1-1c" ,"Team1-1-2a")
hours <- c(NA,150,200,65,20,30, 30)
df <- data.frame(from,to,hours)

# Create data tree
tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df)
###Current Output
print(tree, "hours")
              levelName hours
1 Team1                     NA
2  °--Team1-1               NA
3      ¦--Team1-1-1        150
4      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1a    65
5      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1b    20
6      ¦   °--Team1-1-1c    30
7      °--Team1-1-2        200
8          °--Team1-1-2a    30


#Need to create
actual_hours <- c(NA,35,170, 65,20,30, 30)
df <- data.frame(from,to,hours, actual_hours)
# Create data tree
tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(df)
#Desired output
print(tree, "hours", 'actual_hours')

               levelName hours actual_hours
1 Team1                     NA           NA
2  °--Team1-1               NA           NA
3      ¦--Team1-1-1        150           35
4      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1a    65           65
5      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1b    20           20
6      ¦   °--Team1-1-1c    30           30
7      °--Team1-1-2        200          170
8          °--Team1-1-2a    30           30
```

I'm not sure exactly how to do it since it involves upward and downward movement in the tree? I think using the `height` and/or the `level` attributes of the tree is the way to go but not sure.

Comment: I've put together a solution to this question which involves converting the tree structure back to a dataframe but including the tree level as a variable and using that variable to create the desired data. Will post once I've tidied it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the data.tree looks like this

```
               levelName hours
1 Team1                     NA
2  °--Team1-1                0
3      ¦--Team1-1-1        150
4      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1a    65
5      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1b    20
6      ¦   °--Team1-1-1c    30
7      °--Team1-1-2        200
8          °--Team1-1-2a    30
```

Here are two versions for you to try out as I'm not sure about which one you want.

---

Non-cumulative

```
tree$Do(function(node) {
  node$actual_hours <- node$hours - if (node$isLeaf) 0 else Aggregate(node, attribute = "hours", aggFun = sum)
}, traversal = "post-order")
```

```
> print(tree, "hours", "actual_hours")
               levelName hours actual_hours
1 Team1                     NA           NA
2  °--Team1-1                0         -350 # see here, -350=0-(150+200)
3      ¦--Team1-1-1        150           35
4      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1a    65           65
5      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1b    20           20
6      ¦   °--Team1-1-1c    30           30
7      °--Team1-1-2        200          170
8          °--Team1-1-2a    30           30
```

Cumulative

```
tree$Do(function(node) {
  node$actual_hours <- node$hours - if (node$isLeaf) 0 else Aggregate(node, attribute = "actual_hours", aggFun = sum)
}, traversal = "post-order")
```

```
> print(tree, "hours", "actual_hours")
               levelName hours actual_hours
1 Team1                     NA           NA
2  °--Team1-1                0         -205 # -205=0-(35+170)
3      ¦--Team1-1-1        150           35
4      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1a    65           65
5      ¦   ¦--Team1-1-1b    20           20
6      ¦   °--Team1-1-1c    30           30
7      °--Team1-1-2        200          170
8          °--Team1-1-2a    30           30
```

Comment: Put this into practice today, much more efficient solution than I was in the process of trying which involved converting back to the dataframe and using the tree level to carry out the aggregation. It was the cumulative version I was looking for. Thanks